# Is it possible to declare a typeclass instance for a type alias?

Tags: haskell

I have the code:

```
data Value = A|Two|Three...Ten|J|Q|K deriving (Eq, Ord, Enum)
instance Show Value where
    show A = "A"
    show Two = "2"
    ....
    show K = "K"
```

And another data `Suite` with a similar `Show` instance for `Hearts`, `Spades`, `Clubs`, and `Diamonds`.

If I have

```
type Card = (Value, Suite)
```

Is it possible to create a show function that would transform `(A, Spades)` into the string `"AS"`?

Comment: You could wrap your `(Value, Suite)` into a newtype and write an instance of `Show` for it. Or write a separate function, say `showCard` for the tuple without wrapping.

Comment: What would be the code for either ways?

Answer (score 6):

You should define a `newtype` (or `data` type) for `Card`, the write the `Show` instance for it.

```
newtype Card = Card (Value,Suite)

instance Show Card where
  show (Card (v,s)) = show v ++ show s
```

You could also enable `TypeSynonymInstances` and write the instance for `Card` as you wrote it.

Edit: I should probably also mention that a type synonym is not the idiomatic/Haskell-ish way to handle your situation. A `Card` is semantically different from a pair of `Value` and `Suite`, which could represent (for example) some initial condition in a card game, and not necessarily an actual card.

Answer (score 5):

You probably ought to define your own data type instead of using `(,)`.

```
data Card = Card Value Suite

instance Show Card where
    show (Card v s) = show v ++ show s
```

Comment: I need to create a show function while leaving `Card` as `type`

Answer (score 3):

To define an instance for `type` you need to use the `TypeSynonymInstances` extension. In your case `instace Show Card` would be equivalent to `instance Show (Card, Suite)`. This is not allowed without the `FlexibleInstance` because standard type classes only allow instance of things like `Show (a,b)`.

Now, using `FlexibleInstance` wouldn't be enough because `Show (a,b)` is already defined and your new instance will overlaps with the default one.

How does the compiler chose between your instance of `Show (Card, Value)` and the standard one for `Show (a,b)`? (Using a type is not enough as a type is like doing text substitution.)

To solve the problem of overlapping instance you need to use the `OverlappingInstance` extension. This is a bit tricky and usually not recommended.

Comment: Overlapping instances are not my favorite things. But an overlapping instance of a standard class for a standard type is just *evil*.